# volume control with in application in android?

Tags: android

I am preparing an app.My app have one options button with sound on and sound off.For that i used following code,

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
  int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Unfortunately, the volume setting for that application would still reflect on the system volume setting for the stream type the application is using. What I would like to know is how to set the volume for that application only without affect the system setting.

Is it possible in android have full control over the volume of the app? Is there any method that could do that? Must I do this with code? please help me

Answer (score 0):

You could use AudioTrack, a lower level sound API. It has an setStereoVolume() which operates independent of the system volume.